# Show that prime polynomial is irreducablr

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials, prime-factorization

Let p be a prime number. Question is for any prime value of p the polynomial $$1+\frac{x}{1!}+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+...++\frac{x^p}{p!}$$ is irreducable. I found out that it seems like a taylor series but I couldnt solve the question.

Comment: I dont think that I understand your point. Can you explain your solution more detailed?

Comment: This is actually irreducible for all integer exponents, but for non-prime it is harder to prove. If you are interested look for Irreducibility of truncated exponentials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiply by $p!$, and apply the Schönemann-Eisenstein theorem with the prime $p$.